# how to copy incremental data from on-premises MySql to Azure MySql when on-premises MySql has no date field for reference using ADF

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to copy from on-premises mysql to azure mysql using ADF. Some tables have date filled so, that I can use tumbling window feature and populate incremental data. But some of the tables don't have any date filled for reference.

Is their any feature to get incremental data for such tables?

Comment: Some tables may not have date, but dont you have a numerical ID? How is your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience,data fields(such as createTime,modifyTime) have to be produced when you design table structure.It's significant for log monitor,troubleshooting and increment.As @Martin said in the comment,you always need to have a field to determine the criteria for increments.

If it is acceptable, you could add data field(just auto completed,no need to change your other strategy) to guaranteed consistency from now on.If the table can't be modified,maybe you need to consider adding other residence for new data at the same time.For example, Azure table storage,which you could control columns.

Comment: it is strict that I cant change on source

Comment: @sande Pity,then maybe you could consider reproduce data replica for ADF operations,for example,Azure Storage.